# External web page API access with Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, http

Can you use an `XMLHttpRequest` to access an API such as [the police API](https://data.police.uk/docs/) or the [World Bank API](https://datahelpdesk.worldbank.org/knowledgebase/articles/889392-api-documentation)? If so, how does the site circumvent Same-Origin Policy?

Comment: @Alexander Possible, but this isn't about any site, just APIs

Comment: Same-Origin Policy does not recognize a difference.

Comment: @Alexander So, no, I cannot access these APIs with JavaScript?

Comment: Exactly, the restrictions are the same, regardless of the URL.

Comment: Have you even tried making a request to any of these APIs in JavaScript? `fetch('https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street-dates')` seems to work without any issues.

Comment: @faraz Well, not yet. I was trying to see whether it is worth writing a program to use an API tomorrow

Comment: Your question is entirely moot since there's no CORS issue to begin with...